# Making at least One Checkbox mandatory out of the given checkboxes on submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have the several check boxes inside of the form group. How can I made this **Area of Interest** checkbox mandatory on submit? At least the user clicks on one checkbox before submitting. I have used react-bootstrap.

Any help are appreciated.

```js
<Form.Group>
    <Form.Label>Area of Interest</Form.Label>
    <Form.Check
        name="areaOfInterest"
        label="Dedicated Teams"
        id="dt"
        value={"Dedicated Teams" || formInput.areaOfInterest}
        onChange={handleCheck}
    />
    <Form.Check
        name="areaOfInterest"
        label="Cloud Expert Advice &amp; Support"
        id="ceas"
        value="Cloud Expert Advice &amp; Support"
        onChange={handleCheck}
    />
    <Form.Check
        name="areaOfInterest"
        label="Software Development"
        id="sd"
        value="Software Development"
        onChange={handleCheck}
    />
    <Form.Check
        name="areaOfInterest"
        label="Digital Transformation"
        id="dit"
        value="Digital Transformation"
        onChange={handleCheck}
    />
</Form.Group>
```

Comment: On Submit you can check areaOfInterest value if it is blank or have some value in it.

Comment: [react bootstrap validations](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-validation-native) here is the official link for you  where form validations are given, you can pass check the validation in handleSubmit function, as you receive form there, check it at least one checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On form *submit* you can check the existence of *checked* checkbox, if there is not any checked you can `return false`.

**Demo:**

```js
function submitForm(){
  if(!document.querySelector(':checked'))
    return false;
};
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return submitForm()">
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
  <label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
  <label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
  <label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label><br>
  
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check before submitting the form if `areaOfInterest` has any value to it or not. If it doesn't, show user an error telling them it's a compulsory. If `areaOfInterest` has even a single response to it, let the form submit.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you handle state. I assume you are saving the checkbox's state somehow, like an array or object. One way to do this is to make a function to check the checkbox's state. If it's empty you can disable save or either send an error message.